# Odds of nonconsecutive number draw

Tags: probability, puzzle

What are the odds that you will randomly draw 10 non consecutive numbers from a deck of 40 cards (i.e. numbered 1-40)? (answer should be in a X:1 format, with X representing the average # of drawings you would have to do for one "successful" drawing; "consecutive" means the new card is not within 1 of the previous card in either direction)

Comment: Are you going to draw just 10 cards or the whole deck?

Comment: just 10 cards will be drawn

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this problem as counting the number of binary strings with 40 bits and 10 non-consecutive ones. So you'll have 40-10=30 zeros, which gives you 31 "gaps" between zeros. So you just need to fill 10 gaps now.

$31 \choose 10$ ways to fill the gap.

$40 \choose 10$ ways total to choose 10 numbers from 40.

So your ratio would be $31 \choose 10$:$40\choose 10$.

In the "$X:1$" format, that would be  $19.11:1$

Comment: This would be assuming that none of the 10 cards should be consecutive with each other.  The question though seems to be saying that we just don't want any card to be consecutive with the card drawn before or after it.

Comment: ^ yes this is correct